# Regex Match string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

This should be a nice easy one for a regex expert.

I have a group name `<APP>_<Resource>_<Action>` the action segment contains a combination or CRUD. There are 13 possible combinations that these can appear in.

CRUD, CRU, CRD, CUD, RUD, CR, CU, CD, RU, RD, UD, C, R, U, D

I just want a regex to match on of those patterns within the action segment of the group name. The application and resources can change to various different strings.

Example Group Names

PM_folder1_cru,
PM_folder2_ud,
PM_folder3_cr,
PM_folder4_cu,
PM_personalFolder_crud

Thanks in advance

## EDIT

This is currently done using:

```
$allowedActions = ['CRUD', 'CRU', 'CRD', 'CUD', 'RUD', 'CR', 'CU', 'CD', 'RU', 'RD', 'UD', 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D'];

if (in_array(strtoupper($action), $allowedActions)) {
```

Comment: CRD ah yeah, its still early i will just edit the post. and no it doesn't need to match an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
^C?R?U?D?$
```

To avoid matching empty strings, you can use a lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!$)C?R?U?D?$
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^.*_(?=[CRUD]{1,4})C?R?U?D?$/i
```

**usage:**

```
$arr = array(
'PM_folder1_cru',
'PM_folder2_ud',
'PM_folder3_cr',
'PM_folder4_cu',
'PM_personalFolder_crud',
);

foreach ($arr as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/^.*_(?=[CRUD]{1,4})C?R?U?D?$/i', $str)) 
        echo "OK : $str\n";
    else
        echo "KO : $arr\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
OK : PM_folder1_cru
OK : PM_folder2_ud
OK : PM_folder3_cr
OK : PM_folder4_cu
OK : PM_personalFolder_crud
```

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>**Note:** This answer is assuming that `APP` contains only letters and `Resource` contains only letters and numbers.</sub>

You could do a more general matching by using a character class:
`(?i)[a-z]+_[a-z0-9]+_[crud]{1,4}`. Note that this will also match `DRUC`, `DDDD`, `RRC` for example.

If you don't want that, then you could use something more specific:
`(?i)[a-z]+_[a-z0-9]+_(?:c?r?ud?|cr?d?|r?d|r)`

**What does this mean ?**

- `(?i)` : set the `i` modifier to match case insensitive
- `[a-z]+` : match letters one or more times
- `_` : match one underscore
- `[a-z0-9]+` : match letters and numbers one or more times
- `_` : match one underscore
- `(?:c?r?ud?|cr?d?|r?d|r)` : match `crud, cru, rud, c, r, d etc...`

**PHP code:**
If you want to get the action in a separate (sub)array, you'll may add a named group and remove `?:`:

```
$string = 'PM_folder1_cru,
PM_folder2_ud,
PM_folder3_cr,
PM_folder4_cu,
PM_personalFolder_crud';
preg_match_all('#(?i)[a-z]+_[a-z0-9]+_(?P<action>c?r?ud?|cr?d?|r?d|r)#', $string, $m);
print_r($m['action']); // Get actions
print_r($m); // everything ?
```